# Run Menpo and Menpofit with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, package, menpo

I trying to explore Menpo and Menpofit with PyCharm IDE. I have installed required packages but I have some issue:

1. from .fastpwa import CLookupPWA; 
   ImportError: cannot import name 'CLookupPWA'
2. from .normals import compute_normals;
   ImportError: No module named 'menpo.shape.mesh.normals'

So how I can run Menpo and Menpofit with PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install the required packages? With the `conda` instructions, or via `pip`?

The error you are seeing there is because `CLookupPWA` and `compute_normals` are compiled Python extensions that need to be built before the package can be loaded. The easiest way to do this is to use the `make` command in the Menpo top level, which runs `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`.

If you are on Windows, things start to get pretty tricky, because you need to be able to compile the code properly. Take a look at the instructions [here](http://www.menpo.org/blog/2014/07/python_windows_development/) which try to explain how to properly set up Visual Studio 2008.